# dataset to use for question formation from any text

Tags: nlp, nltk, nlp-question-answering, nlg

I am trying to create an improved quiz generator that accepts a certain text as an input and forms questions from the sentences. I want to create a machine learning model that splits the sentence into different parts so it is capable of forming different questions from the same sentence. For example: from the sentence "Amazon river is the longest river in South America." should form questions: What is the longest river in South America? Is Amazon river the longest river in South America? Where is Amazon river located? etc. If possible, I would also like it to get the context from multiple sentences and then form one question from multiple sentence information. I want it to be able to perform well on any text, not just specific topic. How should I make my dataset or which dataset should I use?

I don't have a lot of previous knowledge on the topic, so I was thinking of somehow using nltk.pos_tag() which specifies everyword in a sentence. I am just not sure how to use it in my model and dataset.

Answer (score 1):

What you're attempting to do is non-trivial and is related to the task of Automatic Question Generation (AQG) which looks at converting structured or unstructured *declarative* natural language sentences into valid *interrogative* forms. Various automated linguistic (rules-based) and statistical methods have been employed. I'd recommend reading [[1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.12811.pdf) by Blšták & Rozinajová, particularly Section 2 which summarises some of the datasets and methods available. The survey by Lu & Lu [[2]](https://aclanthology.org/2021.rocling-1.21.pdf) provides a recent overview of the field. It seems like the most common approach is to leverage existing QA datasets (e.g. SQuAD, HotpotQA et cetera, see Table 5 of [[2]](https://aclanthology.org/2021.rocling-1.21.pdf)). In terms of more practical, quick ways to get started without having to train your own ML/DL model, you could use existing Transformer-based models from HuggingFace such as `iarfmoose/t5-base-question-generator` available [here](https://huggingface.co/iarfmoose/t5-base-question-generator) which takes concatenated answers and context as an input sequence, e.g.:

```
<answer> answer text here <context> context text here
```

and will generate a full question (interrogative) sentence as an output sequence. According to the author, it is recommended that a large number of sequences be generated and then filtered with [iarfmoose/bert-base-cased-qa-evaluator](https://huggingface.co/iarfmoose/bert-base-cased-qa-evaluator).

### References

[[1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.12811.pdf) Blšták, M. and Rozinajová, V., 2022. Automatic question generation based on sentence structure analysis using machine learning approach. Natural Language Engineering, 28(4), pp.487-517.

[[2]](https://aclanthology.org/2021.rocling-1.21.pdf) Lu, C.Y. and Lu, S.E., 2021, October. A Survey of Approaches to Automatic Question Generation: from 2019 to Early 2021. In Proceedings of the 33rd Conference on Computational Linguistics and Speech Processing (ROCLING 2021) (pp. 151-162).